# rust struct fields generating by macro

Tags: rust, macros

I want to create a macro which on the received model generates structures with all its fields and implements trait Default, but faced such problem.
My macro struct_field! is recognized as a field, not a macro inside the model!.
Мaybe someone knows how to solve this problem

```
macro_rules! struct_field {
    ($fild_name:ident: string = $def_val:expr,) => {
        pub $fild_name: Arc<RwLock<String>>
    };
    
    ($fild_name:ident: string = $def_val:expr, $($fields:tt)+) => {
        pub $fild_name: Arc<RwLock<String>>
        struct_field!($($fields)+)
    };

    ($fild_name:ident: bool = $def_val:expr,) => {
        pub enable_kernel_settings: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    };

    ($fild_name:ident: bool = $def_val:expr, $($fields:tt)+) => {
        pub $fild_name: Arc<AtomicBool>,
        struct_field!($($fields)+)
    };
}

macro_rules! model {
    ($model:ident { $($inner_model:ident : $inner_model_name:ident { $($fields:tt)+ },)+ }) => {
        pub struct $model {$(
                $inner_model: $inner_model_name,
        )+}

        $(pub struct $inner_model_name {
            struct_field!($($fields)+) // <-- error
        })+
    };
}
```

error:

```
error: expected `:`, found `!`
--> .../mod.rs:43:29
   |
43 |                   struct_field!($($fields)+)
   |                               ^ expected `:`
...
48 | / model! {
49 | |     MainStruct {
50 | |         inner_struct1: InnerStruct1 {
51 | |             feild1: bool = true,
...  |
58 | |     }
59 | | }
   | |_- in this macro invocation
```

example:

```
model! {
    MainStruct {
        inner_struct1: InnerStruct1 {
            feild1: bool = true,
        },
        inner_struct2: InnerStruct2 {
            feild1: bool = false,
            feild2: bool = false,
            feild3: string = "ignore",
        },
    }
}
```

expected result:

```
pub struct MainStruct {
    inner_struct1: InnerStruct1,
    inner_struct2: InnerStruct2,
}

pub struct InnerStruct1 {
    feild1: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

pub struct InnerStruct2 {
    feild1: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    feild2: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    feild3: Arc<RwLock<String>>
}
```

you can test this with "cargo expand"
and you should be enabled rust-nightly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to C-like macros, Rust macros can only operate on valid AST nodes, that is, they can only be passed something that can be tokenized and, if needed, parsed to some extent, and can only "return" a valid AST node. This, in particular, rules out the invocation of a macro that would be extended as a field definition, because something like `a: bool` is not a valid AST node.

It is still possible to make a macro to do what you want to do, using [function-style procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#function-like-procedural-macros), but it may become somehow more convoluted.

Comment: The only way to make this valid is to pass the whole struct to the macro.